# Returning unique object from Active Record Association Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm having trouble with a simple `has_many` relationship. I'm trying to return unique objects, but because I'm putting restraints on the object in the middle of the relationship, I'm getting an undefined method on my ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation.

I have:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :session_enrollments
 has_many :session_details, through: :session_enrollments


class SessionDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :customers, through: :session_enrollments
 belongs_to :trainer

class Trainer < ActiveRecord::Base

 has_many :session_details
 has_many :session_enrollments, through: :session_details
 has_many :customers, through: :session_enrollments


class SessionEnrollment < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :customer, :foreign_key => "customer_id"
 belongs_to :session_detail, :foreign_key => "session_detail_id"
```

I'm trying to return all trainers that have a current session with a customer via:

```
Customer.rb

@trainers = self.session_details.where(state: ["CONFIRMED"]).trainers
```

But the where statement loads an active record association object. How can I include this condition and still return the unique trainers?

Comment: what is the `self` in tha line?

Comment: Customer, sorry thats in Customer.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@trainers = Trainer.joins(:session_details, :customers).where(session_details: {state: "CONFIRMED"}).where(customers: {id: self.id}).distinct
```

Comment: Updated, see if it is your answer.

Comment: @SharvyAhmed this works, but is there a way to only return unique values !? i.e. .uniq?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that `state` is a column in `Customer`, You need to join the records, try this instead

```
@trainers = self.includes(:session_details => :trainer).where(session_details: {state: ["CONFIRMED"]})
```

This query will return customer along with their session details with associated trainers

Comment: Sorry @RSB, I changed `@session_details_array` to `@trainers` Since that was confusing. also state is in the `session_detail` model

Comment: And I believe the `state` is a property of a `SessionDetail`

Answer (score 1):

I'd try this:

```
@trainers = Trainer.joins(session_details: [:session_enrollments]).where(session_details: {state: 'CONFIRMED'}).where(session_enrollments: {customer_id: self.id}).distinct
```

Comment: You do not have to join `session_enrollments`, since Trainer has direct relation with `customers` and `session_details`.

Comment: Well, `joins(:customer)` will need to join through  `session_enrollments` anyway, my way is just 1 join shorter.